# My program is throwing exceptions and I can't figure out why

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a snake game but my code is throwing exceptions and I can't figure out what it might be.

I am creating this snake game because I want to learn more c# since my teacher said that 4th quarter I get to choose what I want to do with my time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace snake_game
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int xposition = 26;
            int yposition = 26;
            int LeftColumn = 1;
            int rightcolumn = 50;
            int topcolumn = 1;
            int bottomcolumn = 50;
            string[,] map = new string[51, 51];

            map = buildWall(LeftColumn, rightcolumn, topcolumn, 
            bottomcolumn, map);

            //places down the player and updates the map to tell where you are
            Console.SetCursorPosition(xposition, yposition);
            Console.Write((char)2);
            map[xposition, yposition] = "player";

            map = generateRandomApple(map, LeftColumn, rightcolumn, 
            topcolumn, bottomcolumn);

            placeApple(map);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void placeApple(string[,] map)
        {
            //places down the apple
            for (int x = 0; x < map.Length; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map.Length; y++)
            {
                if (map[x, y].Equals("apple"))
                {
                    Console.Write("a");

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static string[,] generateRandomApple(string[,] map, int lc, int 
    rc, int tc, int bc)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int xposition;
        int yposition;

        while (true)
        {

            //generates random cordinates to place down the apple
            xposition = rnd.Next(lc, rc);
            yposition = rnd.Next(tc, bc);

            //sets the property that the apple wants to be at to the apple 
            if it isnt open in the map
            if ((!map[xposition, yposition].Equals("the wall")) && 
            (!map[xposition, yposition].Equals("player")))
            {
                map[xposition, yposition] = "apple";

                break;
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    private static string[,] buildWall(int leftcolumn, int rightcolumn, int 
    topcolumn, int bottomcolumn, string[,] map)
    {

        //generates the left and right walls
        for (int i = leftcolumn; i <= rightcolumn ; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(leftcolumn, i);
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Write("#");

            map[leftcolumn, i] = "the wall";

            Console.SetCursorPosition(rightcolumn, i);
            Console.Write("#");
            map[rightcolumn, i] = "the wall";
        }

        //generates the top and bottom walls
        for (int i = topcolumn; i <= bottomcolumn; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(i, topcolumn);
            Console.Write("#");
            map[i, topcolumn] = "the wall";

            Console.SetCursorPosition(i, bottomcolumn);
            Console.Write("#");
            map[i, bottomcolumn] = "the wall";
        }

        return map;
     }
   }
 }
```

It is supposed to set up the map but the if statement in the function `getRandomApple` is throwing exceptions specifically the part that checks if the spot has the player in it, the exception it is throwing is saying that a

```
NullReferenEexception was being unhandled(object reference not set to an 
instance of an object).
```

Can anyone help me figure out what might be throwing the exceptions? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: What exceptions are you seeing? If you edit the question and include the exception messages and line numbers that would help us help you.

Comment: `if it isnt open in the map` needs to be commented out, as well as the `are` right before `Console.SetCursorPosition(xposition, yposition);`

Comment: The edit you made helps slightly, but it would much better if you could include the actual stack trace from the exceptions you're seeing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: If you look at the stack trace of the exception you will see the line that caused the exception - use the debugger & point a break point on that line & examine the values - you should be able to find which one is null.

Comment: @Wyck I edited on the OP's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

In your `generateRandomApple` method, you have the following `if` statement:

```
if ((!map[xposition, yposition].Equals("the wall")) && (!map[xposition, yposition].Equals("player")))
```

When you populate your `map`, you don't add something to every index, so values at many of the `map[xposition, yposition]`s are `null`. So when you call `.Equals()` on those values in your `if` check, you are getting a null pointer exception. Try performing a null check before calling `.Equals()`, or using the equivalence operator instead.